# Can I show a progress indicator when the file loading code is not in a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, wpf, progress, indicator

All the examples I've seen show the "long loop" in a BackgroundWorker.  Although I understand that that is the correct way to do it, my problem is that the code was not originally written this way and it would be complicated to put it into a BackgroundWorker. Is there any way at all that I could create a ProgressBar in the StatusBar, or in a modeless  popup, without changing the file loading code? Thank you.

Comment: Is the code not in any sort of thread at the moment? Either way you can "create a progressbar".. but if its currently not in a thread, your file loading code no doubt blocks the UI thread.. and therefore any updates to the progress bar will not be visible anyway.

Comment: In WPF/Silverlight/Metro you can use data binding. If the file is being loaded on a background thread and you have a public property of which contains the percent of file that has been loaded then you can bind this property to the value of the progress bar and it will be updated when the property is updated. An easier solution, but might not be as good: you can also set the progress bar to an indeterminate state (it shows that it's loading the file, but not how much is done/remaining) while the file is being loaded.

Comment: No, you can't do this without running the load code on a thread different from the UI thread. BackgroundWorker itself isn't required, but a different threa dis.

Answer (score 0):

Only way that you can really do this is if your long running code can be split into multiple sections in which case, you can do something like this:

```
//long running code
DoSomethingStage1();

progressBar.Value = 30;
Application.DoEvents(); // update the GUI

DoSomethingStage2();

progressBar.Value = 60;
Application.DoEvents(); // update the GUI

DoSomethingStage3();

progressBar.Value = 100;
Application.DoEvents(); // update the GUI
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

This is a bit of a hack though - better to bite the bullet and move the code out to a separate thread if you can.